# Estimate how many values fall below a specific deviation using the empirical rule

Tags: c#, math, standard-deviation

I'm trying to estimate how many values fall within a portion of the standard deviation.  Using the empirical rule we can state that:

34% of all the values will fall between the average and 1 standard deviation
13.4% of all values will fall between 1 standard deviation and 2.

As depicted here:

[image]

This rule can only tells me the % of values which fall within an integer standard deviation, however I'm trying to calculate how many fall within fraction of a standard deviation.  Let's take this example:

```
public decimal GetEastimatedNumberOfValuesWithinDistribution(int sampleSize, decimal average, decimal deviation, decimal newDataPoint)
{
    var priceDifferential = newDataPoint/sampleSize;
    var newAverage = average + priceDifferential;
    var averageDistance = average - newAverage;
    var fractionalDeviation = averageDistance / deviation;
    //How do I return the average number of points between that fall within the average to the newAverage
}
```

Normally If I had the full dataset I could iterate over it and manually check,  However in this case I only have information about the dataset and not all of the data.

How do I estimate the amount of data points that will fall within a fraction of a deviation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a normal distribution, the percentage of values falling within `k⋅σ` of the mean is [given by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_deviation_and_coverage) `erf(k/sqrt(2))` where `erf` is the [error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) [function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html). For example, `erf(1/sqrt(2)) =` [`0.682689..`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=erf%281+%2F+sqrt%282%29%29) and `erf(3/sqrt(2)) =` [`0.997300..`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=erf%283+%2F+sqrt%282%29%29).

C# does not have an `erf` function built into the math package (unlike [python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.erf)). Numerical approximations can be found on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Numerical_approximations), or [what reference should I use to use erf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22834998/what-reference-should-i-use-to-use-erf-erfc-function) on SO.

Comment: +1 for the answer, I'll mark as complete when I get back to that project tonight. Also just to clarify (since I don't have a background in math),  k is a representation of the number of standard deviations I use, so in this case it would be my `fractionalDeviation` and as for the `error function` is that a uniform function e.g is will always work for bell curves?

Comment: @johnny5 Right, `k = 1, 2, 3` will return the `0.68, 0.95, 0.997` numbers shown in your graph. The error function is [smooth](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+erf%28x%29+for+x+from+0.25+to+3), and it works for the "normal" bell curves i.e. those that follow the [68-95-99.7 rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule).

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. I've been watching stats videos to try to learn but I  certain things I still get confused on.  This saved me hours of trying to interpret math symbols I don't know

Comment: Where did this formula come from? It appears at least twice on Wikipedia but is "citation needed" both times.

Comment: @Era That comes straight from the definition of the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Applications).